# How to create and append a variable in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to be able to do

```
filter {

   if [type] == "mobile" + x
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

where x is a string that is a number.
This will let mobile1, mobile2, mobile3, etc be filtered in the same way.

Is there any way that is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do with the following config

```
filter {
    if [type] =~ /mobile.+/
    {
        ......
    }
}
```

It is a regular expression, when the `type` has the word `mobile`, it will go in the if statement.